# Section numbering gone after etoolbox use?

Tags: numbering, titlesec

I am using Kile 2.1 on Ubuntu 16.04. I have been trying to make corrections for my dissertation concerning the table of contents. After trying a number of options including a couple `etoolbox` patches I restored my custom `.sty` file back to the original form. **Now I no longer have numbering before section headings**. This is independent of the class (e.g. report or article). I have no idea what permanent change I have made. I have no idea how to correct this issue.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. How should we answer this, seeing not a single line of code?

Comment: Are you perhaps loading `titlesec`?

Comment: Yes, I am using titlesec. If I remove the package from the preamble the section numbering returns. Has this package been modified?

Comment: @JeffWebber A version of `titlesec` had a bug; update your TeX distribution.

Comment: Thank you everyone! My apologies for the extremely vague question. Obviously, I confused changes I had made with the lack of numbering. The updated titlesec package has corrected the issue.